# jQuery strip first period

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Forgive me if this is a double post, but I couldn't find a similair one that worked for me.

I have a domain name ex. `google.co.uk` (but this can also be google.com). I need to split this on the first period so I get an array object like this: `["google", "co.uk"]` or `["google", "com"]`

In antoher post I found this: `'google.co.uk'.split(/.(.+)?/)[1];` but that doesn't seem to work...

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the first . with something else that will never turn up in the string (such as |), then split off that character.

As str.replace only replaces the first instance of the character it finds by default, the code is pretty simple:

```
str = "google.co.uk";
str.replace(".", "|").split("|");
```

Comment: Ah, so simple, why didn't I thought of that?! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYyH6/)**

```
var text = 'google.co.uk';

//Returns the position of the first '.'
var index = text.indexOf('.');

//Grab the the start of the string up to the position of the '.'
var first = text.substring(0, index);

//Start from the '.' + 1(to exclude the '.') and go to the end of the string
var second = text.substring(index + 1);

alert(first); //google
alert(second); //co.uk
```

Comment: A -1 with no comment for improvement and the code works? Curious...

Answer (score 0):

You're all making this a bit complicated. It's possible in one easy line:

```
var domain = 'google.co.uk';
alert(domain.split(/^(.+?)\./ig).splice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some native  javascript functions...

```
string='google.com';
dot=string.indexOf('.',0);


name=string.substring(0,dot);
domain=string.substring(dot+1,string.length);

arr= new Array(name, domain);
alert(arr);
```

Lol, already see better solutions... :) and similar solutions too...